# A Java-based Readability-like parser

Tags: java, html-parsing, readability

I would like to know what standalone options exist for parsing and converting normal webpages to the easy to read format, provided by services like Pocket, Readability, and Instapaper.

I am primarily looking for a Java parser library to include in my app, but in general, all kinds of standalone tools are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't seem to find any pages even describing this "easyread" file format.  You sure it's not some proprietary stuff?

Comment: easyread is a term that I invented. It is basically parsing and stripping the main text of an article from the boilerplate page stuff, in order to make it easier to read

Answer (score 6):

Snackatory now itself states that it's outdated and recommends using [Crux](https://github.com/chimbori/crux).

But there's also [Readability4J](https://github.com/dankito/Readability4J). It's a Kotlin port of Mozilla's Readability.js, which is used for Firefox's Reader View. So Readability4J's output matches exactly Firefox's Reader View.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Readability4J. But I just ported it, kudos for the great work go to Mozilla: https://github.com/mozilla/readability.

Comment: wow, thank you, you did a great job. I spend a lot of time transfer my project from Mozilla's Readability.js to Java/Kotlin library, great repo.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are after [Snacktory](https://github.com/karussell/snacktory) which appears to be state of the art for java these days replacing jreadability.

Comment: i would be careful labeling amateurish libraries as "state-of-the-art", Snacktory will fail for streams larger than 2048 bytes. The proof is in the pudding: de.jetwick.snacktory.Converter#detectCharset. `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2048
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at de.jetwick.snacktory.Converter.detectCharset(Converter.java:191)
 at 
`

Answer (score 0):

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is the first library that comes to mind.  It's ideal for scraping HTML.  You can easily strip all tags out of a web page, leaving only text.  (If you know the structure of the target pages, you can just use a particular selector to get the piece you want, or exclude the pieces you want.)

Then again, you might just be wanting something like [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), which will try its best to render a web page as a PDF.

Comment: Not bad if all you want is to remove HTML-tags. Not enough if you want to actually remove distracting ads and navigation bars and all that stuff.